# How to stop repeated printing "JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring"?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have one Spring application (Spring version 3.1, Java version jdk1.7) is running which is configured with Apache Camel 2.14.2 version as well. The main function of this application to read/write files from various folder paths and Routes are defined in Camel route XML. And this application has many RESTful webservice deployed and receives such RESTful webservice calls from other client applications and from outside also.

The problem is last few weeks it is showing following lines repeatedly and thereby generated a huge log at end of the day.

How can I stop this repeated printing?

```
08:15:36,401 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (http--10.9.101.131-9443-120) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
08:15:36,401 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (http--10.9.101.131-9443-146) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
08:15:36,416 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (http--10.9.101.131-9443-89) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
08:15:36,416 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (http--10.9.101.131-9443-9) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
```

Comment: Do you have a log4j.xml or log4j.properties in your project ?

Comment: No. Log4j not configured.

Comment: Then configure Log4j and set debug level for AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to NONE.

Comment: I can configure Log4j but could not set debug level to NONE. Please help me. How to do that.

Comment: Show what you have done.